# Using hist in Matlab to compute occurrences

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, histogram

I am using `hist` to compute the number of occurrences of values in a matrix in Matlab.

I think I am using it wrong because it gives me completely weird results. Could you help me to understand what is going on?

When I run this piece of code I get `countsB` as desired

```
rng default; 
B=randi([0,3],10,1);
idxB=unique(B);
countsB=(hist(B,idxB))';
```

i.e.

```
B=[3;3;0;3;2;0;1;2;3;3];
idxB=[0;1;2;3];
countsB=[2;1;2;5];
```

When I run this other piece of code I get wrong results for `countsA`

```
A=ones(524288,1)*3418;
idxA=unique(A);
countsA=(hist(A,idxA))';
```

i.e.

```
idxA=3148;
countsA=[zeros(1709,1); 524288; zeros(1708,1)];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want [`histcounts`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to count the number of occurrences of each element in `A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to the other answers: you can replace `hist` by the explicit sum:

```
idxA = unique(A);
countsA = sum(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), idxA(:).'), 1);
```

Comment: Is it as fast as or faster than `hist` for `size(A,1)` very large?

Comment: I always [bet on `bsxfun`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303542/2586922), but better test yourself for your specific case

Comment: When `idxA` and `A` have huge length (e.g. 8000 and 1316966) it gives me error because `Error using bsxfun
Requested 1316966x8000 (9.8GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of
arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive.
See array size limit or preference panel for more information` However, when size limits are not exceeded, it is faster than `hist`.

Answer (score 3):

idxA is a scalar, which means the number of bins in this context.
setting idxA as a vector instead e.g. [0,3418] will get you a hist with bins centered at 0 and 3418, similarly to what you got with idxB, which was also a vector

Answer (score 2):

I think it has to do with:

```
N = HIST(Y,M), where M is a scalar, uses M bins.
```

and I think you are assuming it would do:

```
N = HIST(Y,X), where X is a vector, returns the distribution of Y
among bins with centers specified by X.
```

In other words, in the first case matlab is assuming that you are asking for 3418 bins

Comment: Do you know any other better way to count occurrences?